# Как использовать выводимые значения из функции print() дальше в assert. ЯП Python (Питон)

Tags: python, cookie, print, assertion

Я делаю запрос на сервер и в ответ получаю куки. Заранее я не знаю имя и значение куки, но мне нужно написать ассерт на то, что в ответ всегда приходит одинаковое имя куки и что оно вообще есть.
Предлагается читать имя куки функцией print()
но я не понимаю как после принта использовать эти значения дальше в ассершенах.
Вот кусок вызова запроса к серверу

```
  response = requests.get(url)
  cookie_value = dict(response.cookies)
  print(cookie_value)
```

Задание требует обязательного использования print() т.е я должна узнать имя и значение куки с помощью принт и использовать дальше в ассерте.

Comment: Что значит значение из принта? Вы же в переменную `cookie_value` положили это значение, так со значением переменной и сравнивайте дальше

Comment: Задание требует обязательного использования print() т.е я должна узнать имя и значение куки с помощью принт и использовать дальше в ассерте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### С обязательным использованием `print()`

Если в задаче предполагается использование `print()` именно здесь, то это довольно странно. Но если это так, то, видимо, в задаче также предполагается использование `input()`. Это означает, что вам нужно после вывода увидеть глазами то, что вам нужно, и ввести имя куки через `input()`:

```py
name = input()
key = cookie_value[name]
```

#### Альтернативное

Но возможно, что вы не совсем понимаете поставленную перед вами задачу. `print` выводит уже имеющуюся у вас информацию — здесь он не нужен и, скорее всего, он нужен где-то в другом месте. В *cookie_value* уже лежит всё, что вам нужно — просто извлеките эту информацию оттуда.

Объясните, пожалуйста, какая структура у *cookie_value* — что там находится и что вы там ищете? Если там лежит всего лишь одна пара ключ-значение, которые вам как раз и нужны, то тогда вы легко можете получить их, используя следующую конструкцию:

```py
name, value = list(cookie_value.items())[0]
```

Если там лежит больше информации, то тогда вам точно нужно знать, по крайней мере, где находится то, что вы ищете. Допустим, если в *cookie_value* находится много данных, но вы точно знаете, что искомые вами имя и значение куки находятся последними, то вы можете написать так:

```py
name, value = list(cookie_value.items())[-1]
```

Решение также зависит и от того, что вы ищете. Возможно, вам нужно взять куки, у которого имя является числом или в имени присутствует какая-то строка. Тогда и решение будет отличаться.

#### UPD: дополнительное решение

Кажется, в задании просто просят вывести содержание *cookie_value* — все его ключи и значения. Решений может быть несколько:

```py
for key, value in cookie_value.items()
    print(key, value)
```

```py
for key in cookie_value:
    print(key, cookie_value[key])
```

---

Похоже, есть небольшой пробел в умении пользоваться словарями. Хотел бы порекомендовать почитать соответствующую [статью о словарях](https://timeweb.com/ru/community/articles/slovari-v-python-i-metody-raboty-s-nimi), в которых подробно описаны их возможности и в частности о том, как получать данные из словарей с помощью `items()`.

Comment: cookie_value имеет структуру ключ : значение, но часть задания звучит как: "Необходимо с помощью функции print() понять что за cookie и с каким значением" отсюда я предположила что после того как я эту куки получила и распарсила вывести значение в консоль.

Comment: Тогда, судя по всему, вам нужно просто их вывести. Сейчас дополню ответ.

Comment: Разобралась с заданием. Принт надо было использовать просто для  того, что бы увидеть что фактически приходит с сервера и ассерт завязать на конкретное имя куки. Спасибо за ответы!